# Update on Varchar column of a table that has > 10 millions rows 

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Recently we are facing severe performance issues in our `Update` statements, earlier the update used to take 3 mins and now the update is taking nearly 2 hours. Do to the recent db design we changed the stored procedure code as below.

Here is  my scenario in detail: I have very big fact table with more than 10 millions rows, and I need to update a column of that fact table when a condition is met. So we wrote an update statement to update that column:

```
declare @var  varchar(max) = (select metrcikey from metricdim where metrciname ='XYZ')

Update 
    fopty
set 
    Metrickey = metrickey+','+@var 
from 
    optyfact opty 
inner join  
    optydim dim on opty.optyid = dim.optyid
inner join 
    geodim geo on geo.atukey = opty.atukey 
inner join 
    agreementdim ag on opty.optyid = ag.optyid 
inner join 
    account acc on acc.optyid = acc.optyid 
where 
    dim.optytype= 'ABC'
    and geo.atukey =145
    and ag.agreementtype ='Sold'
    and acc.accountteamManager  ='XXX'
```

Is there any way to optimize the above query, as per my understanding the statement that is making to execute the query for 2 hours is because of SET statement

```
Metrickey = Metrickey + @var
```

here `Metrickey` column is `varchar` and `@var` variable is also `varchar(max)`, to concatenate this string it is taking more time.

It would be a great help for me if the above query can be optimized, so please suggest best method to update a `varchar` column with a `varchar` value.

Comment: What is the actual data type of `metrickey` - is it `max` or is there a defined length?  Part of the issue could be the use of `max` datatype in your variable.

Comment: Are their indices on the fields in your `WHERE` clause?  How about the fields being joined?  What's the approximate row count for each table?  What does your query plan show you (i.e., which steps have the greatest % of cost)?

Comment: Agree with @JNK but wanted to add even if the datatype is a max datatype, does it really need to be?

Comment: What's the query plan for your query?  10 million rows is not so many, unless you end up with some kind of nested table scan (i.e. polynomial behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

There's no real secret superfast solution for updating a VARCHAR column.  It's going to be relatively slow no matter what, but there are things you can do to lessen the pain.

Make sure that you've got proper covered indexes on all your tables.

NOTE: I'm going to assume that your code has a typo in it - "Update fopty" should read "Update opty", correct?

In the case of the optyfact table (opty alias), you should have an index on the `optyid` and `atukey` columns which includes `metrickey`.

For the other tables, put all the columns in the index - don't worry about including (covering) any other columns.

Once you've got all this set up, go through the query analyzer to make sure that you're doing INDEX SEEKs on all the tables, otherwise this is gonna run for a LONG time, like you indicated.

Beyond that, make sure you're joining on narrow columns.  INTs are good, VARCHARs are bad.

Last thing: make sure that the `metrickey` column is NOT part of your clustered index, or the table is going to keep reorganizing itself during the update.

That's all I got.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider updating this in batches (say, 100,000 rows at a time) instead of trying to update all of the rows in one shot. It won't necessarily take less time overall, but it won't lock up everything for two hours. We can dump the actual optyid values into a temp table so we don't have to continuously reference the base tables in the update.

```
CREATE TABLE #q(rn INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, optyid INT);

DECLARE 
  @rc    INT, 
  @step  INT = 1,
  @chunk INT = 100000; 

INSERT #q(optyid) SELECT DISTINCT opty.optyid
FROM dbo.optyfact AS opty 
INNER JOIN dbo.optydim AS dim      ON opty.optyid = dim.optyid
INNER JOIN dbo.geodim AS geo       ON geo.atukey = opty.atukey 
INNER JOIN dbo.agreementdim AS ag  ON opty.optyid = ag.optyid 
INNER JOIN dbo.account AS acc      ON acc.optyid = acc.optyid 
WHERE 
  dim.optytype = 'ABC';
  AND geo.atukey = 145
  AND ag.agreementtype = 'Sold'
  AND acc.accountteamManager = 'XXX';

SET @rc = @@ROWCOUNT;

WHILE @step <= ((@rc / @chunk) + 1)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    UPDATE o SET MetricKey += ',' + @var
    FROM dbo.optyfact AS o
    INNER JOIN #q AS q ON o.optyid = q.optyid
    WHERE q.rn BETWEEN (((@step-1)*@chunk)+1) AND (@step*@chunk);

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    CHECKPOINT;
    SET @step += 1;
END

DROP TABLE #q;
```